# returns x with the n bits that begin at position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving other bits unchanged

Tags: c, implementation, bit-manipulation

my solution

```
get the rightmost n bits of y
a = ~(~0 << n) & y

clean the n bits of x beginning from p
c = ( ~0 << p | ~(~0 << (p-n+1))) & x

set the cleaned n bits to the n rightmost bits of y
c | (a << (p-n+1))
```

it is rather long statements. do we have a better one?

```
 i.e
x = 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
p = 4
y = 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
n = 3

the 3 rightmost bits of y is 0 1 0 
it will replace x from bits 4 to bits 2 which is 1 1 1
```

Comment: the "n bits that begin at position p" go from `p` to `p+n-1`...  So why does `p-n+1` show up in your expression (twice)?

Comment: the whole manipulation includes two parts, I am talking about beginning from rightmost parts: bits [p-n+1,p], and bits [0,p-n+1]. We want to change the value of the firs part and keep the second part unchanged.

Comment: Right, but the bits from [p-n+1,p] are the n bits _ending_ at position p, not the n bits _starting_ at position p as your question says.  (Assuming bits "start" from 0...)  I think you need to fix your code or fix your question...

Comment: begins from p assuming iterate the bits string from left to right. Yes, you are right, I should have made it clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I would phrase it just like you did in your comment:  "From bit p-n+1 to bit p."  If you say a bit string "begins at bit 7 and ends at bit 5" I bet 50% of programmers would take issue with that phrasing :-)

Comment: Read my answer here: [**To Set all bits One from n to m**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917454/set-the-m-bit-to-n-bit/15918195#15918195)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote similar one:

```
 unsigned setbits (unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y)
{
  return (x & ~(~(~0<<n)<<(p+1-n)))|((y & ~(~0<<n))<<(p+1-n));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasonable approaches.

One is yours:  Grab the low n bits of `y`, nuke the middle `n` bits of x, and "or" them into place.

The other is to build the answer from three parts:  Low bits "or" middle bits "or" high bits.

I think I actually like your version better, because I bet `n` and `p` are more likely to be compile-time constants than `x` and `y`.  So your answer becomes two masking operations with constants and one "or"; I doubt you will do better.

I might modify it slightly to make it easier to read:

```
mask = (~0 << p | ~(~0 << (p-n+1)))
result = (mask & a) | (~mask & (y << (p-n+1)))
```

...but this is the same speed (indeed, code) as yours when `mask` is a constant, and quite possibly slower when `mask` is a variable.

Finally, make sure you have a good reason to worry about this in the first place.  Clean code is good, but for something this short, put it in a well-documented function and it does not matter that much.  Fast code is good, but do not attempt to micro-optimize something like this until your profiler tells you do.  (Modern CPUs do this stuff very fast; it is unlikely your application's performance is bounded by this sort of function.  At the very least it is "innocent until proven guilty".)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following descriptive code:

```
int setbitsKR(int x, int p, int n, int y){
    int shiftingDistance = p - n + 1,
        bitmask = (1 << n) - 1, // example, 11
        digitsOfY = (y & bitmask) << shiftingDistance, // whatever        
        bitmaskShiftedToLeft = bitmask << shiftingDistance, // 001100
        invertedBitmaskShiftedToLeft = ~bitmaskShiftedToLeft; // 110011

    // erase those middle bits of x
    x &= invertedBitmaskShiftedToLeft;

    // add those bits from y into x
    x |= digitsOfY;

    return x;
}
```

In short, it creates a bitmask (string of `1`s), shifts them to get to that middle position of `x`, nukes those bits of `x` by `&`ing with a string of `0`s (inverted bitmask), and finally `|`s that position with the right digits of `y`.