# set the m-bit to n-bit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a `32-bit` number and without using for loop, I want to set `m` bit **to** `n` bits.

For example:

`m` bit may be `2nd` or `5th` or `9th` or `10th`.
 `n` bit may be  `22nd` or `27` or `11th` bit.

I assume (m < n).

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: Combine the left shift operator `<<` with the bitwise and `&`. Details are left as an exercise to you...

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: @perreal OK I read only question statement,  So I thought he need to put `1` at `n` and `m` position. his question is unformatted.

Comment: @vijay panwar: I think your question is not bad, But You should show some efforts that what you have tried?, also explain your question correctly some peoples are confuse what you asked...Below I have posted my answer may be you find helpful..

Comment: duplicates: [What is the best practice way to create a bitmask for a range of bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21465833/995714), [Masking bits within a range given in parameter in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28035794/995714), [uint64_t setting a range of bits to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48436659/995714), [Fastest way to produce a mask with n ones starting at position i](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39321580/995714), [Obtain a specific subset of bits of an int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16001819/995714), [set the m-bit to n-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15917454/995714)

Answer (score 14):

Suppose Bits are numbered from LSB to MSB:

```
BIT NUMBER    31                                     0
               ▼                                     ▼
number bits    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0101 
               ▲    ^           ^                    ▲ 
              MSB   |           |                   LSB
                    |           | 
                   n=27        m=17

LSB - Least Significant Bit (numbered 0)
MSB - Most  Significant Bit (numbered 31)
```

In the figure above, I have shown how bits are numbered from LSB to MSB.
Notice the relative positions of `n` and `m` where `n > m`.

---

### To set (all one) bits from n to m

---

To set-**`1`** all bits from position **`m`** to **`n`** (where `n > m`) in a 32-bit number.
You need a 32-bit mask in which all bits are **`1`** from `n` to `m` and remaining bits are **`0`**.

For example, to set all bits from **`m=17`** to **`n=27`** we need mask like:

```
BIT NUMBER    31   n=27        m=17                  0
               ▼    ▼           ▼                    ▼
mask =         0000 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

And if we have any 32-bit number, by bitwise OR (**`|`**) with this number we can set-**`1`** all bits from `m` to `n`. All other bits will be unchanged.

**Remember** OR works like:

```
x | 1 = 1   , and 
x | 0 = x
```

where  `x` value can be either `1` or `0`.

So by doing:

```
 num32bit = num32bit | mask;
```

we can set `n` to `m` bit `1` and remaining bits will be unchanged. For example, suppose, `num32bit` = `0011 1001 1000 0000 0111 1001 0010 1101`,

then:

```
0011 1001 1000 0000 0111 1001 0010 1101   <--- num32bit
0000 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000   <--- mask     
----------------------------------------  ---------------Bitwise OR operation  
0011 1111 1111 1110 0111 1001 0010 1101   <--- new number  
---- ▲           ▲  -------------------
     |-----------|   this bits are from `num32bit`
      all bits are   
      1 here
```

This is what I mean by:

```
     num32bit = num32bit | mask;
```

##How to make the mask?

To make a mask in which all bits are `1` from `n` to `m` and others are `0`, we need three steps:

1. **`Create mask_n`**: All bits on Right side from `n=27` are one

   ```
    BIT NUMBER     31  n=27                              0
                   ▼    ▼                                ▼
    mask_27=       0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
   ```

   In programming this can be created by right-shift (`>>`) 4 times.

   And, **why `4`?**

   ```
    4 = 32 - n - 1  ==> 31 - 27 ==> 4
   ```

   Also note: the complement (`~`) of `0` has all bits one,
   and we need [unsigned right shift](/q/2429479) in C.
   Understand the [difference between signed and unsigned right shift](/q/15457893#15457908)
2. **`Create mask_m`**: All bits on left side from `m=17` are one.

   ```
    BIT NUMBER    31              m=17                  0
                  ▼                ▼                    ▼
    mask_17       1111 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000
   ```
3. **`Create mask`**: Bitwise AND of above to: `mask = mask_n & mask_m`:

   ```
    mask =         0000 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000
                        ▲           ▲
    BIT NUMBER          27          17
   ```

And, below is my `getMask(n, m)` function that returns a unsigned number that looks like mask  in step-3.

```
#define BYTE 8
typedef char byte; // Bit_sizeof(char) == BYTE
unsigned getMask(unsigned n,
              unsigned m){
    byte noOfBits = sizeof(unsigned) * BYTE;
    unsigned mask_n = ((unsigned)~0u) >> (noOfBits - n - 1),
             mask_m = (~0u) << (noOfBits - m),
             mask = mask_n & mask_m; // bitwise & of 2 sub masks
    return mask;
}
```

To test my `getMask()` I have also written a `main()` function and a binary() function, which prints a given number in binary format.

```
void binary(unsigned);
int main(){
    unsigned num32bit = 964720941u;
    unsigned mask = 0u;
    unsigned rsult32bit;
    int i = 51;     
    mask = getMask(27, 17);
    rsult32bit  = num32bit | mask;  //set n to m bits 1
    printf("\nSize of int is = %ld bits, and " 
           "Size of unsigned = %ld e.g.\n", sizeof(int) * BYTE,
                                            sizeof(unsigned) * BYTE);
    printf("dec= %-4u, bin= ", 21);
    binary(21);
    printf("\n\n%s %d\n\t   ", "num32bit =", num32bit); 
    binary(num32bit);
    printf("mask\t   "); 
    binary(mask);
    while(i--) printf("-");
    printf("\n\t   "); 
    binary(rsult32bit);
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void binary(unsigned dec){
  int i = 0,
      left = sizeof(unsigned) * BYTE - 1;
  for(i = 0; left >= 0; left--, i++){
    printf("%d", !!(dec & ( 1 << left )));
    if(!((i + 1) % 4)) printf(" ");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

This test code runs like (the output is quite same as I explained in above example):

```
Output of code: 
-----------------
$ gcc b.c 
:~$ ./a.out 

Size of int is = 32 bits, and Size of unsigned = 32 e.g.
dec= 21  , bin= 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0101 

num32bit = 964720941
           0011 1001 1000 0000 0111 1001 0010 1101 
mask       0000 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000 
---------------------------------------------------
           0011 1111 1111 1110 0111 1001 0010 1101 
:~$
```

Additionally, you can write  `getMask()` function in shorter form in two statements, as follows:

```
unsigned getMask(unsigned n,
                 unsigned m){
    byte noOfBits = sizeof(unsigned) * BYTE;
    return ((unsigned)~0u >> (noOfBits - n - 1)) &
           (~0u << (noOfBits -m));
}
```

<sup>**Note:** I removed redundant parentheses, to clean up the code. Although you never need to remember precedence of operators, as you can override precedence using `()`, a good programmer always refers to precedence table to write neat code.</sup>

A better approach may be to write a macro as below:

```
#define _NO_OF_BITS sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT
#define MASK(n, m)  (((unsigned)~0u >> (_NO_OF_BITS - n - 1)) & \
                    (~0u << (_NO_OF_BITS - m)))
```

And call like:

```
result32bit  = num32bit | MASK(27, 17);
```

---

### To reset (all zero) bits from n to m

---

To reset all bits from n to m = 0, and leave the rest unchanged, you just need complement (`~`) of `mask`.

```
mask      0000 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 
~mask     1111 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111 1111 1111   <-- complement
```

Also instead of `|` operator to set zero `&` is required.

remember **AND**  works like:

```
x & 0 = 0   , and 
x & 0 = 0
```

where `x` value can be 1 or 0.

Because we already have a bitwise complement `~` operator and and  `&` operator, we just need to do:

```
rsult32bit  = num32bit & ~MASK(27, 17);
```

And it will work like:

```
num32bit = 964720941
       0011 1001 1000 0000 0111 1001 0010 1101 
mask   1111 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111 1111 1111 
---------------------------------------------------
       0011 0000 0000 0000 0111 1001 0010 1101
```

Comment: +1 for effort on your part :)

Comment: {stackoverflow} Chat

Comment: `num |= mask` is the same as `num = num | mask` and is less typing. Same for `num &= mask. Looks like you might have just been trying to be clear. That was quite long and to be honest, Tl;Dr. BUT good job on the effort.