# Obtain a specific subset of bits of an int in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

How would I obtain a specific subset, say bits 5-10, of an int in Java?

Looking for a method where one can pass in specific bit positions. I'm not sure how I would create a mask that changes given the input, or even if that is how one should go about doing it.

I know this is how one would get the front say 10 bits of an int: (I think)
int x = num >> 22;

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not google `bit masks` and try to create such a method yourself, people will be more likely to help if they see effort.

Comment: [What is the best practice way to create a bitmask for a range of bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21465833/995714), [Masking bits within a range given in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28035794/995714), [setting a range of bits to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48436659/995714), [Fastest way to produce a mask with n ones starting at position i](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39321580/995714), [Creating a mask around a subsection \[i,j\] for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56508967/995714), [set the m-bit to n-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15917454/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a number `n`, and want bits from `i` to `j` (i=5, j=10).

Note, that `i=0` will give you the last bit

```
 int value = n & (((1 << (j-i)) - 1) << i );
```

will give you the result.

The left part is obvious: you have a value, and you will put a bitmask on it.

The value of the mask is `((1 << (j-i)) - 1) << i`. It says:

- Take a `1` bit  (value: `0000000000000001`)
- Shift it left `j-i` times (value: 2^(10-5) = 2^5 = 32 = `0000000000100000`)
- Deduct 1 (value: 31 = `0000000000011111`) - have you seen the lowest bits reversed?
- Shift it left `i` times (value: 31*32=992 = `0000001111100000`)

So, you have got the bitmask for bits 5 - 10  (more precisely, from 5 to 9, since 10th is not included).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain value of bit 1 (bits are indexed from 0 to 31)

```
int val = bits & 0x002;
```

To obtain value of bit 16

```
int val = bits & (1<<16);
```

To obtain value of bit n

```
int val = bits & (1<<n);
```