# Masking bits within a range given in parameter in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am new to C programming and not sure that there is already a good explanation for how to do this, if so I am sorry. I am trying to set the bits within a range given to me. the function signature looks like:

```
unsigned int setBits(int low, int high, unsigned int source) {
```

`source` being the number to be operated on, `low` being the lowest bit in the range, and `high` being the highest bit in the range. I understand bit-shifting just fine when trying to get specifically the last 4 bits or first 4 or any combination thereof, but do not understand how to get the bits from a range that will be changed in the parameter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: something along the line of `(1<<high)-(1<<low)`, depending on whether `high`/`low` are inclusive or not.

Comment: they are inclusive, counting right to left from 0 with low being rightmost. I have already handled exceptions for them being equal or for low > high. Are you saying that is what my mask should be made of and then | the mask with my source?

Comment: Get n bits from position p for number x.. do something like....

return ((x >>(p+1- n) & ~(~0 << n))

Comment: and to determine n bits subtract low from high to know the number of bits? then use high for positon p?

Comment: SleuthEye, the actual mask ends up being `(1<<(high+1))-(1<<low)` if high is inclusive (which seems implied here).

Answer (score 3):

If its inclusive

```
mask = ~(~0 << (end - start + 1));
value = (n >> start) & mask;
```

where n is the original integer, and value is the extracted bits.

Comment: N is your original integer. or parameter in your case..from where you are extracting out the bits..

Comment: I have a test program that returned this:  setBits(0, 31, 0): failed. 
 Expected result: ffffffff.
 Your result: 0.
setBits(0, 0, 0): failed. 
 Expected result: 1.
 Your result: 0.
setBits(31, 31, 0): failed. 
 Expected result: 80000000.
 Your result: 0.
setBits(28, 31, 0xf): failed. 
 Expected result: f000000f.
 Your resetBits(0, 3, 0xf0000000): failed. 
 Expected result: f000000f.
 Your result: 0.
setBits(0, 3, 0xf000000f): failed. 
 Expected result: f000000f.
 Your result: f.
setBits(4, 7, 0xf0000000): failed. 
 Expected result: f00000f0.
 Your result: 0.

Comment: Then please paste your test program here. What kind of variables are you using? Signed, or unsigned?

Comment: unsigned int setBits(int low, int high, unsigned int source)                        
 33 { } is the method signature. the test program I do not have permissions to, it is on a server for a class. sorry it isnt of more help. the method signiture is unsigned, as is the source that contains the bits that I need to operate on, i used an int for the mask.

Comment: Your question is "how to get the bits from a range that will be changed in the parameter.", and the function I mentioned gives the range. I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

2 approaches: Iterative method to set bit in `source` from `low` to `high`:

```
unsigned int setBitsI(int low, int high, unsigned int source) {
  while (low <= high) {
    source |= 1u << low;
    low++;
  }
  return source;
}
```

Non-iterative method:

```
unsigned int setBitsNI(int low, int high, unsigned int source) {
  unsigned setmask = 1u << (high - low);
  setmask <<= 1;
  setmask--;
  setmask <<= low;
  return source | setmask;
}
```

Important to avoid `1u << (1u + high - low)` for when `high` is "bit-width-1" and `low` is 0, `1u << bit_width` is UB.

Should `low` or `high` have an value outside the bit range, problems occur.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some simple examples of shifting and creating masks to motivate the more general expression.

```
1             == 00001b
1<<2          == 00100b
(1<<2)-1      == 00011b
((1<<2)-1)<<2 == 01100b
```

So,

```
((1<<(high-low+1))-1)<<low
```

Answer (score -1):

This was my solution:
The if statements at the front just cover conditionals about low and high. This is passing all the tests I was given.

```
unsigned int setBits(int low, int high, unsigned int source)
 {
 if (low < 0)         {return source;}
 else if (high > 31)  {return source;}
 else if (low > high) {return source;}
 else {
         unsigned int mask = 0xFFFFFFFF << (31 - high);
         mask = mask >> ((31 - high) + low);
         mask = mask << low;
         return source | mask;
     }
```

}