# Optimising bitwise operations in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I had a problem in hand as this    :
"Exercise 2-6. Write a function setbits(x,p,n,y) that returns x with the n bits that begin at
position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving the other bits unchanged."

I've written a function for this as below. This is working as expected.

```
int func_setx(int x,int p,int n,int y)
{
    int a_t= ~0 << (p+n);
    int b_t= ~a_t >> n;
    int x_t= x& (a_t | b_t);    // a temporary x which has the bits to be changed as 0 , rest of the bits unchanged.

    int mask= (y << p) & (~(~0 << (p+n)));     // a mask which has required bits from y in positions to be set , rest all bits 0.

    printf("\nCheckpoint : mask= %x  x_t= %x\n",mask,x_t);

    int result= mask|x_t;
    return result;
}
```

But I somehow feel the logic is long and can be optimized, but can't think of any other way yet.
Can anyone suggest any optimization to this please?

Comment: You'll probably find an answer at [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) — and you should bookmark the page even if you don't find the answer there.

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [k&r exercise confusion with bit-operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076084/kr-exercise-confusion-with-bit-operations) and [returns x with the n bits that begin at position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving other bits unchanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727351/returns-x-with-the-n-bits-that-begin-at-position-p-set-to-the-rightmost-n-bits-o) and [Setting Bits in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590545/setting-bits-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make an `n` bit mask:

```
mask_y = (1U << n) - 1;
```

To start it at bit `p`:

```
mask_x = mask_y << p;
```

Clear the appropriate bits in `x`:

```
x &= ~mask_x;
```

Extract the bits from `y`:

```
y &= mask_y;
```

Upshift them to position `p`:

```
y <<= p;
```

Put it all together:

```
result = x | y;
```

Or in a more compact form:

```
mask = (1U << n) - 1;
result = x & ~(mask << p);
result |= (y & mask) << p;
```

Comment: Assuming 32-bit integers, if `n == 32`, this solution causes undefined behaviour.  That case is just `return y`, though, so it's easy to special-case.  Alternately, use `1ULL` (or however you want to get a 64-bit type) instead of `1U`.

Comment: +1 for not just giving the code but also explaining what it does step-by-step

Comment: Carl, your comment should properly be part of your answer.

Comment: It's more of an aside than part of the answer, really, which is why I left it a comment.  NBD.